# c# send data to comport

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Im making a WindowsForm app to simulate current values to a meter. I dont know how to take the values from the text box and send it trough the COM port. 
this is the code i got at the moment

```
namespace ValueSim1
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void comboBox1_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Get all serial ports name
        string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();

        // Clear comboBox list to get latest serial ports in each dropdown.
        comboBox1.Items.Clear();

        foreach (string port in ports)
        {
            // Output serial port to dropdown list.
            comboBox1.Items.Add(port);
        }
    }

    private static SerialPort serialPort1;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   

        if (comboBox1.Text != "")
        {
            serialPort1.PortName = comboBox1.Text; //comboBox1.Text set to PortName

            serialPort1.BaudRate = 19200; //Baudrate is set (fix.)

            //if serial port has opened, it must be closed at first.
            if (serialPort1.IsOpen == true)
            {
                serialPort1.Close();
            }
            //open the serial port after confirmation serial port closed.
            if (serialPort1.IsOpen == false)
            {
                serialPort1.Open();

                if (serialPort1.IsOpen == true) //message window shows serial port status.
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Open Success\n" + serialPort1.PortName.ToString() + " " + serialPort1.BaudRate.ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("COM Port error");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void groupBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox5_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the documentation for the SerialPort class : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport(v=vs.110).aspx

There is a Write(string) method, so

```
serialPort1.Write(comboBox1.Text);
```

should work
See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2sxhat8(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: So i got 5 parameters like Intensity, frequency etc and a button, when i press it i want to send all those parameters to the meter. If i put the serialPort.write commands in the button_click that should do it?

Comment: You would need to know what the meter is expecting as input & format the string you send accordingly. Does the meter expect the parameters to be comma separated, in a particular order separated by CRLF, fixed length parameters - so as long as it expecting a string input & you format it correctly then that should work. If the meter is expecting other encodings eg byte values then one of the other Write methods may be appropriate.

Comment: back with a question. if i try to open a port i get this:Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in ValueSim1.exe "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: As a guess - you don't appear to have created an instance of the SerialPort. _"private static SerialPort serialPort1;"_ creates a reference to a SerialPort that is initialised to null. Somewhere (possibly the Form1 constructor) you need to create a new instance of the class - _"serialPort1 = new SerialPort();"_ If that is not the problem, then you will need to step through your code with the debugger to find where the exception is thrown. It would also be good practice to wrap code that potentially throws exceptions in a try..catch block so you can handle the exceptions.

Comment: actually i did add "private static SerialPort serialPort1 already. the exception is thrown at the serialPort1.PortName = comboBox1.Text; line

Comment: See what I wrote above - _"private static SerialPort serialPort1 "_ - does not create an instance of the class. It creates a reference variable initialised to null, hence the null reference exception.

Answer (score 0):

use
            `SerialPort1.WriteLine(string);`
e.g

```
     SerialPort1.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);
```

There are also other overload for the `Write()` and `WriteLine()` method which can be used. make sure you read the documentation properly.

[here is a link to the microsoft documentation for the serial port class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport(v=vs.110).aspx)

Try reading it as you code.

Comment: back with a question. if i try to open a port i get this:Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in ValueSim1.exe "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: instead of  private static SerialPort serialPort1; use                          private static SerialPort serialPort1 = new SerialPort();